# How can I force rhythmbox to use direct-connection instead of system-wide proxy settings?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, rhythmbox

On my work computer, I need to set the proxy for web browsing.

I'd like to use rhythmbox to stream internet radio, but it usually fails with "Cannot resolve the proxy hostname".  So, I want to avoid those settings for rhythmbox.

Is there a way to force rhythmbox to use direct connection for internet radio streams?  I've tried setting the **HTTP_PROXY** envar to various values with no help.

Note it works if I revert to direct connect in Firefox or Chrome, then connect the "radio" in rhythmbox.  I can then set the browser proxy back to normal, and rhythmbox continues to work -- but I have to repeat the manual process the next time I want to stream audio.

Also, running a local proxy isn't really a solution in this case.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?